# Session getting expired before timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api, session-state

I have configured the cookieless session_state in ASP.Net Web API and timeout is 20 minutes.

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="20" />
```

On every new session established I am storing session_id generated in a dictionary to keep track of sessions, and respectively removes the session_id from dictionary whenever session_end.

But I am facing a strange issue (not very frequently), whenever a new user establishes the session it is expired immediately and the session_id is removed from the dictionary.

Session_End code:

```
protected void Session_End()
    {
        var sessionId = this.Session.SessionID;
        if (SessionDictionary.ContainsKey(sessionId))
        {
            SessionDictionary.Remove(sessionId);
        }
    }
```

So please if someone can guide me on this.
Also, I have a doubt whether "this.Session.SessionID" refers to session_id which is expired or the one which is currently created.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm curious why you need to keep track of sessions.

Comment: I am storing data in the session for each corresponding user, that's why

Answer (score 0):

Are you behind a load balancer? If so you could just be hitting a server in your farm that doesn't actually have the session setup as its specific to each server as you declared it as  in process

Comment: Yeah we are, but for that we implemented sticky session. But for debugging it more, we used single server and then also we faced this problem